# How to associate model data with a user in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a built-in way of associating persistent model data with an authenticated user in MVC4, or are you supposed to provide your own implementation?

The MSDN tutorials I've read don't suggest how to do it, but I've seen a `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` property I could store. For example, a model for a site that allows the user to upload photos:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; } // Controller sets WebSecurity.CurrentUserId?
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Or is there an "MVC way"?

Comment: Just store the user ID as a column in your data table. No reason to make things any more complicated.

Comment: we created a custom page base that inherits PageBase and in that set user and company information.  Then in all of our controllers we inherit the custom page base so that all user and company information is available on every controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you not use something like this:

```
public class Photo
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int UserID { get; set; } 
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
public UserProfile user {get;set;}
...
}

public class UserProfile
{
 public int UserID { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: This seems valid, but I think the `Photo.UserID` property becomes redundant. `UserProfile` was generated in the Internet project template, and in the database it added a `User_UserId` column with a FK constraint. Seems odd that it's nullable though.